# Lilypond: How does one control the size of the repeat symbol( : )

Tags: lilypond

My apologies. I've trimmed it down as far as I am able. 
Just to try to be clear, when the ChordName font size and the BarLine bar-extent are increased, the colon (repeat symbol) stays at the default size. My question is how to adjust the size of the colon(repeat symbol)?

Thank you for your time.

```
\version "2.14.2"
\book { 
    \score {
     \new ChordNames \with {
     \override BarLine #'bar-extent = #'(-1 . 20)
     \override ChordName #'font-size = #20
     \override ChordName #'extra-offset = #'(0 . -1)
     \consists "Bar_engraver"
     }
     {
       \relative a' {
         \chordmode {
           \partial 4*3  s4 s4 s4
           \repeat volta 2 { a1 g a a  }
         }}}
        \layout {
            indent = 0.0 \cm
            \context {
                \Score
                \remove "Bar_number_engraver"
          }}}}
```

Comment: It would really help if you provide a minimal working example in your question. If the problem is with the usage of `:`, do you really need to link another file and give such a complex example? See: http://lilypond.org/tiny-examples.html